Applications of Category to Ordinary Differential Equations
Before we begin, I should say I am aware there is the study of D-modules if one wishes to apply category theory to partial differential equations. Moreover, you could argue Petri nets and, more generally, Fong's theory of decorated cospans is an example application of category theory to ODE's.
However, I wanted to see if anyone knew any other ways in which category theory could be used to analyze solutions to ODE's.

This question is about a method in search of a problem. As such it may not be an approach that leads to interesting mathematics. To make this approach interesting, how about starting with an open or difficult question about area A (here: ODEs) that could be solved or solved better using theory M (here: category theory)?

Unfortunately, I don't specialize in ODE's, so I wouldn't have any intuition about which open problems would lend themselves to category-theoretic approaches. I could bring up stuff like the second half of Hilbert's 16th problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_sixteenth_problem) or ideas from Wandering domains (https://www.math.purdue.edu/~eremenko/dvi/wandering.pdf) but those would simply be shots in the dark.
My point with this question was to see if anyone who specialized in the field knew about efforts to apply category theory, since it is quite a pervasive topic.
